# Date as alias names in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to alias few columns to date values and got stuck trying different ways.

```
SELECT  
   r.RET_MAIN_DSC,
   max(case when day_dt=Convert(date, getdate()-7) and EXT_SALES_AMT2>0 then 'X' else '-' end) as a,
   max(case when day_dt=Convert(date, getdate()-6) and EXT_SALES_AMT2>0 then 'X' else '-' end) as b,
   max(case when day_dt=Convert(date, getdate()-5) and EXT_SALES_AMT2>0 then 'X' else '-' end) as c,
   max(case when day_dt=Convert(date, getdate()-4) and EXT_SALES_AMT2>0 then  'X' else '-' end) as d,
   max(case when day_dt=Convert(date, getdate()-3) and EXT_SALES_AMT2>0 then 'X' else '-' end) as e,
   max(case when day_dt=Convert(date, getdate()-2) and EXT_SALES_AMT2>0 then 'X' else '-'  end) as f,
   max(case when day_dt=Convert(date, getdate()-1) and EXT_SALES_AMT2>0 then 'X'  else '-' end) as g,
   max(case when day_dt=Convert(date, getdate()) and EXT_SALES_AMT2>0 then 'X' else '-' end) as h
FROM 
    GNL_STR_POS_ACT_1000_F POS
JOIN 
    VC_RET_COUNTRY RET ON POS.RET_COUNTRY_ID = RET.RET_COUNTRY_ID
JOIN 
    VC_RETAILER r on r.RET_ID=ret.RET_ID
WHERE 
    DAY_DT BETWEEN GETDATE() - 8 AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY  
    r.RET_MAIN_DSC
```

I am trying to alias each column to the `day_dt` value.

For example, for column name a the alias name has to be `getdate()-7`.

Please can someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Can you not just simply type it?

Comment: That would be an awful alias imho but to use reserved words and other characters not allowed in a normal column name you have to wrap the name in square brackets. ie [Your Crazy getdate() alias - 7 here]

Comment: I was trying the value of the date to be as the column name but not the exact letters. The output has to look like this                        RET_MAIN_DSC 4/13/2015
xyz x
abc x

Comment: Export it to excel and type your headers there, or write an SSRS report.  Short of that...Maybe write an unpivot then re-pivot with the column names.  Encapsulation.

Comment: Oh boy, I would recommend running away as quickly as possible from using the value as your column names. That should be done in your report instead. To do that in t-sql means you have to use dynamic sql which is kind of nuts just to name the columns.

Comment: If it's an absolute requirement, you could use dynamic sql.  But I'd really recommend just naming them generically like Date1, date2,... etc.  Then modify the report headers in whatever you are rendering the report with.

Comment: Sean i absolutely agree with you that it needs to be done at the front end, but this is something that needs to be done in sql :(

Comment: Then you are going to have to use dynamic sql for this. There really isn't much leeway there.

Comment: is it a script or a stored proc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you will need to use Dynamic sql for this, something like this....

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql = N' SELECT  r.RET_MAIN_DSC,
max(case when day_dt=Convert(date, getdate()-7) and EXT_SALES_AMT2>0 then ''X'' else ''-'' end) as '+ QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()-7, 120)) +',
max(case when day_dt=Convert(date, getdate()-6) and EXT_SALES_AMT2>0 then ''X'' else ''-'' end) as '+ QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()-6, 120)) +',
max(case when day_dt=Convert(date, getdate()-5) and EXT_SALES_AMT2>0 then ''X'' else ''-'' end) as '+ QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()-5, 120)) +',
max(case when day_dt=Convert(date, getdate()-4) and EXT_SALES_AMT2>0 then ''X'' else ''-'' end) as '+ QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()-4, 120)) +',
max(case when day_dt=Convert(date, getdate()-3) and EXT_SALES_AMT2>0 then ''X'' else ''-'' end) as '+ QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()-3, 120)) +',
max(case when day_dt=Convert(date, getdate()-2) and EXT_SALES_AMT2>0 then ''X'' else ''-'' end) as '+ QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()-2, 120)) +',
max(case when day_dt=Convert(date, getdate()-1) and EXT_SALES_AMT2>0 then ''X'' else ''-'' end) as '+ QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()-1, 120)) +',
max(case when day_dt=Convert(date, getdate()) and EXT_SALES_AMT2>0 then ''X'' else ''-'' end)   as '+ QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120)) +'
 FROM GNL_STR_POS_ACT_1000_F POS
JOIN VC_RET_COUNTRY RET ON POS.RET_COUNTRY_ID = RET.RET_COUNTRY_ID
join VC_RETAILER r on r.RET_ID=ret.RET_ID
WHERE DAY_DT BETWEEN GETDATE()-8 AND GETDATE()
GROUP BY  r.RET_MAIN_DSC'

Exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: I tried using this but since the date value cannot be converted into a string to alias it as a column name the sql is failing, is there any way around to assign date value using the above dynamic sql.         Thanks

Comment: I am not using a Date value as a string, I have user DATENAME function to extract the Day as a string and using that as the Column name, if you copy paste this code as it is , it should work.

Comment: Ya i see that the column names are weekdays for the above code, but i was trying to get actual dates as the aliases.

Comment: as date like what `YYYY-MM-DD` ?